# Can I modify array passed as an argument?

Tags: javascript

Like in title, can I modify array passed as an argument? (without using `return`)

```
function arrayElementsRemove(array, element) {
    array.filter(item => item != element);
}
```

and then

```
it('should remove items from array', () => {
    var array = [1,2,2,3];
    arrayElementsRemove(array, 3);
    expect(array).to.equal([1,2,2]); // fails, array still equals [1,2,2,3]
});
```

Comment: Yes, you definitely can. You could probably have figured that out with a quick test in your browser developer console or Node.js.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrays are passed as reference. Your issue is that [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) does not change the original array, it returns a new one.

Instead of Array.filter, you should do a loop from `length-1` to `0`, and when `element === array[i]` use [`Array.splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) to remove the item.

Your `arrayElementsRemove` function should look like this:

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 2, 3];

function arrayElementsRemove(array, element) {
    for (var i = array.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (array[i] === element) {
            array.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }
}

arrayElementsRemove(arr, 3);

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: I'm jealous of how close you are to 2000 rep, really want me some edit privileges :P